# Return two float arrays and Eigen::Matrix3f from a function

Tags: c++, eclipse, c++17, eigen

I want to return two float arrays and a 3 by 3 Eigen matrix from my function. This is the code I am using:

```
std::tuple<float[3], float[3], Eigen::Matrix3f> dual_quadric_to_ellipsoid_params(Eigen::Matrix4f Q) {
    Q = Q / -Q(3,3);
    float center[3] = {Q(0,3), Q(1,3), Q(2,3)};
    Eigen::Matrix4f T;
    T.block(0, 0, 3, 3) = Eigen::Matrix3f::Identity();
    T.col(3) << -center[0], -center[1], -center[2], 1;
    Eigen::Matrix4f Q_cent = T*Q*T.transpose();
    Eigen::JacobiSVD<Eigen::MatrixXf> svd(Q_cent.block(0, 0, 3, 3), Eigen::ComputeFullU | Eigen::ComputeFullV);
    Eigen::Vector3f singular_vals = svd.singularValues();
    float axes[3] = {singular_vals[2], singular_vals[1], singular_vals[0]};
    Eigen::Matrix3f R = svd.matrixV();
    return {center, axes, R};
}
```

I am getting an error:

```
could not convert ‘{center, axes, R}’ from ‘<brace-enclosed initializer list>’ to ‘std::tuple<float [3], float [3], Eigen::Matrix<float, 3, 3, 0, 3, 3> >’
```

Comment: Don't use `float[3]`, use `std::array<float, 3>`

Answer (score 0):

- The solution here is to change every instance of `float[3]` into `std::array<float, 3>`.

---

The way you created your arrays, `float center[3]`, is often called c-style array. `center` here is actually `float*` type, which is why you get the error `{center, axe, R}` cannot be converted to your desired type. It's actually of `std::tuple<float*, float*, Eigen::Matrix3f>` type.

However, you don't want to do that either. The reason is your `float*`s here are pointing to temporary object created in that function. And those object will be destroyed by the end of that function, and invalidate your pointes.

---

The solution here is to use `std::array`, as it will store the information even after the function:

```
std::tuple<std::array<float, 3>, std::array<float, 3>, Eigen::Matrix3f> foo() {
     ⋮
    std::array<float, 3> center = {Q(0,3), Q(1,3), Q(2,3)};
     ⋮
     ⋮
    std::array<float, 3> axes = {singular_vals[2], singular_vals[1], singular_vals[0]};
     ⋮
    return {center, axes, R};
}
```

Comment: `center` is not a pointer, and no tuple of pointers could be created given the return type.  The issue is that arrays can’t be direct-initialized.